# Why Underfitting? Using LGBM Regression Model Modeling Time Series Data

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lightgbm

#### Problem Statement

Recently I've been trying to train a regression model for time series data. When I trained on an hourly data point (around 7,000 data points), both models showed OKey results.

I did normalization on each feature. then the data pipeline fed into the models.

The following picture is trained by hourly data.

[image: Hourly data]

Furthermore, when I trained on a **daily** data point (around 400 data points) averaging from hourly data, both models seemed **underfitting**.

The following picture is trained by daily data.

[image: Daily data]

#### Current System Information

- Dataset: The dataset is [Air Quality Data Set from UCI](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Air+Quality)
- Packages: What I'm using is `LightGBM` and LSTM of `Keras`
- LGBM

parameters & model

```
    params = {
        'boosting_type': 'gbdt',
        'objective': 'regression',
        'metric': {'l2', 'l1'},
        'num_leaves': 40,
        'learning_rate': 0.01,
        'feature_fraction': 0.9,
        'bagging_fraction': 0.8,
        'bagging_freq': 5,
        'verbose': 0
    }

    gbm = lgb.train(params, lgb_train,
                    num_boost_round=300, # 300 num_iterations is not enough?
                    valid_sets=lgb_eval,
                    early_stopping_rounds=5)
```

- RNN

parameters & model

```
    # design network            
    model = Sequential()
    # X_train_rnn is the input dataframe
    model.add(LSTM(rnn_hidden_neurons, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', input_shape=(X_train_rnn.shape[1], X_train_rnn.shape[2])))
    model.add(Dense(1))
    model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='adam')
    history = model.fit(X_train_rnn, y_train_walk[labelY].values, 
                        epochs=50, 
                        batch_size=32, 
                        validation_data=(X_test_rnn, y_test_walk[labelY].values), 
                        callbacks=callbacks, # Early stopping
                        verbose=2, 
                        shuffle=False)
```

#### My Question Is

Why did I get an underfitting result? Is it because of too few data points?

Any Idea? Thanks in advance!

Comment: How did you formulate the question, i.e. what did you try to predict using what data? What features did you use? How did you split training and validation (i.e. early stopping) datasets? are the two plot identical other than the hourly vs daily model? If so, it seems that in the daily case it is not underfitting in general, but you get a constant prediction of 0 for the daily model

Comment: Hi @MykhailoLisovyi, I tried to predict the time series value of specific feature (ex. benzene concentration). I used walk-forward validation (train: 2 months, test: 1 month). The pictures are different (hourly data vs daily data)

Comment: You will have to investigate why in the daily case the output is 0. It is not underfitting in general, but a special case, when nothing seems to be learned in the training